# Random Node from BST

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I have a method that is suppose to get a random node from a BST in O(n) time. However, it always returns the root node. What is wrong with the logic of my method?

```
    public Node getRandomNode(Node root) {

    // get random value between 0 to size of BST
    Random ran = new Random();
    int ranNum = ran.nextInt(size + 1);
    Node temp = root;

    return getRandomNode(ranNum, temp);
}

int count = 0;
public Node getRandomNode(int ranNum, Node temp) {

    if (temp == null)
        return null;

    count++;

    if(count <= ranNum) {
        temp.left =  getRandomNode(ranNum, temp.left);
        if(count == ranNum)
            return temp;
        temp.right =  getRandomNode(ranNum, temp.right);
    }

    return temp;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at what you're doing, you'll see that no matter what you're doing the only thing you return is temp. On your first call to getRandomNode(...) your temp is the root node and you never modify temp. Therefore, you'll always return the root node.

In order to fix this try the following:

```
if(count <= ranNum) {
    temp = getRandomNode(ranNum, temp.left);
    if(count == ranNum)
        return temp;
    temp =  getRandomNode(ranNum, temp.right);
}

return temp;
```

Comment: Thanks fro your answer. I'm still a bit confused because I thought temp would be modified by doing temp.left = ...; and temp.right...;

Comment: Hey, you should definitely look a bit more into Trees in general.

You changed what the node is pointing to, but that doesn't really affect the node itself.

Comment: You're right. I'll read more about it. So one thing I'm getting away is that you can only change the "structure" of the tree by setting temp equal to whatever ranges you want (e.g. temp.left), right?